# InputStream vs BufferedInputStream

Tags: android

I have the following code:

```
httpUrlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(URL).openConnection();
InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(httpUrlConnection.getInputStream());
BufferedReader reader =  new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
```

My question is, can I just replace the second line with "InputStream in =httpUrlConnection.getInputStream();" ? will it make any difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest no. The info received from the internet comes in packages and the sequence and speed of the packages coming will vary. BufferedInputStream automatically manages them all while InputStream may cause problems. Thanks for posting in the forum!